# Getting a C++ double function to report a message instead of returning a numerical when a certain condition is met

Tags: c++, function

I am very new to C++, and am trying to create a pair of functions that will report two possible real solutions to a quadratic equation. I am also trying to enter a message into these functions that will display in lieu of a solution if no real solution exists.

The functions correctly report real solutions, but when a non-real solution appears, the program will return "The two possible real solutions to this problem are nan and nan," and my error message ("There is no real solution to that quadratic equation. Please enter a different set of numbers") does not show up in the terminal at all.

Here is my code. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" // from a Github page by Bjarne Stroustrup that corresponds with the Programming: Practices and Principles book. Note that I am learning this on my own; it is not for homework.
#include <cmath>


        double quafo1 (double a, double b, double c)
        {

if ((sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))) < 0)
{
cout << ("There is no real solution to that quadratic equation. Please enter a different set of numbers;/n");

}
else {
    double x1 = ((b * -1) + sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
            return x1;
            }

    }

        double quafo2 (double a, double b, double c)
        {

         if ((sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))) < 0) 
         cout << ("There is no solution to that quadratic equation. Please enter a different set of numbers;");

else {
    double x2 = ((b * -1) - sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);

        return x2;
        }


    }

double a;
double b;
double c;
int main()
{
    cout << "This program will solve a quadratic equation as long as one or more real solutions are possible. Please enter values for a, b, and c (separated by spaces and followed by enter, e.g. 3 5 4), after which both possible answers for x will be provided. Please note that a cannot equal 0.\n";
while (cin >> a >> b >> c)
{       
     cout << "The two possible real solutions to this problem are " << quafo1(a, b, c) << " and " << quafo2(a,b,c) << ".\n"; 

}
}
```

Comment: You could always create a single function that returns both roots as `std::pair<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>>`.

Comment: Thank you paddy, this will come in handy in the future. I also recently learned about tuple, which I'm guessing is similar.

Comment: You need to check the argument of `sqrt()` is positive BEFORE calling `sqrt()` - testing the return value means you are checking after `sqrt()` has had a domain error.  Also, since any quadratic equation has either two real solutions (one may be repeated) or none, you may wish to consider ways to return two values (e.g. a `struct` containing both roots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqrt` function will never return a negative value*, so your test `(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))) < 0` will never be TRUE. What you *probably* want to do is test if the argument to `sqrt`is negative:

```cpp
    if (((b*b)-(4*a*c))) < 0) {
        cout << ("There is no solution to that quadratic equation. Please enter a different set of numbers;");
        return nan("");
    }
    else {
        //...
```

Alternatively, if that argument *is* negative, the `sqrt` function will return `NaN`, which you can test for with the [`isnan()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnan/) function:

```cpp
    if (isnan(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))) {
        cout << ("There is no solution to that quadratic equation. Please enter a different set of numbers;");
        //...
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

*Note: Strictly speaking, any (positive) number has two square roots, one positive and one negative: `2 x 2 = 4` but also `-2 x -2 = 4`.*

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly for having overlooked that. I ultimately put the original if statement  (with sqrt() removed) within int main () so that if the calculation was negative, neither function would run to begin with. But it was good to see that the function would still output my "There is no solution . . . " message. Now I can sleep peacefully tonight.

Comment: Not all floating point representations support NaN.   If you are going to use `isnan()`, check `std::numeric_limits<double>::has_quiet_NaN` first.   It is generally better - whether your floating point type can represent a NaN or not - to check values before the error occurs (e.g. before passing a negative value to `sqrt()`) not after.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return NaN itself in those cases:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan

Comment: The functions as they are currently written **do** return `NaN` in those circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few changes to the programme that fix the issues you are having.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" 
// from a Github page by Bjarne Stroustrup that corresponds with the Programming: Practices and Principles book. Note that I am learning this on my own; it is not for homework.
#include <cmath>

double quafo1(double a, double b, double c) {
if ((b*b-4*a*c) < 0)
    return sqrt(-1);
else
    return ((b * -1) + sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
}

double quafo2(double a, double b, double c) {
    if ((b*b-4*a*c) < 0)
        return sqrt(-1);
    else
        return ((b * -1) - sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
}

double a;
double b;
double c;

int main()
{
    cout << "This program will solve a quadratic equation as long as one or more real solutions are possible. Please enter values for a, b, and c (separated by spaces and followed by enter, e.g. 3 5 4), after which both possible answers for x will be provided. Please note that a cannot equal 0.\n";
    while (cin >> a >> b >> c) {    
     double s1 = quafo1(a,b,c),
         s2 = quafo2(a,b,c);
     if (s1==s1 && s2==s2)
         cout << "The two possible real solutions to this problem are " << s1 << " and " << s2 << '.' << endl; 
     else
         cout << "There is no real solution to that quadratic equation. Please enter a different set of numbers." << endl;
    }
}
```

First of all, as @Adrian mentioned above, you need to check whether `b*b-4*a*c` is negative or not and not its square root.

Second, the function **must** return something in all cases. Hence, you must have a return statement for when there are no real solutions. In those cases, you may simply return NaN. One way to do that would be returning `sqrt(-1)` as I did. In fact, you can simply return the solution to the quadratic equation, which would be NaN if no real solutions are possible because the square root of `b*b-4*a*c` is involved.

Now, in `main`, you may check if the returned value is NaN. To check for that, you can use `isnan()`, or check if it is equal to itself, which I did over here. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I appreciate the insights, thank you! Returning NaN is probably better than my original choice of returning 0, since 0 could be very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

An indirect answer is that C++ has *exceptions*, precisely when you cannot return a value. You can define your own exception classes, but `std::out_of_range` makes perfect sense here.

Exceptions are thrown like `throw std::out_of_range("There is no real solution to that quadratic equation.");` and caught with `try { ... } catch (std::exception& e) { std::cerr << e.what() << " Please enter a different set of numbers";}`

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << ("There is no real solution to that quadratic equation. Please enter a different set of numbers;/n");
```

This line should be terminated with "\n", not "/n".  "<< endl;" could be used